# Playing YouTube videos on custom html video playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, youtube

Hello i implemented the custom video playlist at http://jsfiddle.net/Barzi/Jzs6B/9/ Everything works fine except that i cant play youtube videos on my site the code is shown below

HTML

```
<video id="videoarea" controls="controls" poster="" src=""></video>
<ul id="playlist">
    <li movieurl="VideoURL1.webm" moviesposter="VideoPoster1.jpg">First video</li>
    <li movieurl="VideoURL2.webm">Second video</li>
    ...
    ...
</ul>
```

Javascript via jquery

```
$(function() {
    $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
        $("#videoarea").attr({
            "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
            "poster": "",
            "autoplay": "autoplay"
        })
    })
    $("#videoarea").attr({
        "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
        "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
    })
})​
```

and the css

```
#playlist {
    display:table;
}
#playlist li{
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:8px;
}
#playlist li:hover{
    color:blue;                        
}
#videoarea {
    float:left;
    width:640px;
    height:480px;
    margin:10px;    
    border:1px solid silver;
}​
```

any help to get the right URL to play this videos would be appreciated

Comment: You have to use the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Answer (score 0):

Youtube currently uses iframe to embed its video player. Have a look at this [article](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Embedding_a_Player).

What you need to do is retrieve the list of the VIDEO_ID from youtube (unique identifier for each video - something like M7lc1UVf-VE) and update the src of the iframe as you switch video. A basic example as follows:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/cA-T-HLdv7g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div id="change">change video</div>
<script>
$('#change').on('click',function(){
  $('#ytplayer').attr('src','http://www.youtube.com/embed/OmaI1nInDOs');
  });
</script>
```

At the above developers.google.com link it is also explained how one can retrieve playlist based on PLAYLIST_ID. You will also find all current available settings to tune your player.